# IOS Swift Master Detail Application, managed object, tableView: endUpdates() calls configureCell() but crash, reloadData() does not call it

Tags: uitableview, swift, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobject, reloaddata

I am new at Swift and I tried making my first test app but I got stuck on a managed object problem I think ... Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

I started to make an application using the Master Detail Application template and using XCode's storyboard as much as possible to modify the basic template.

I modified the TableView to use custom TableViewCells:

```
import UIKit

class ExpenseItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var whenLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var whatLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I use ManagedObjects:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(ExpenseItem)
class ExpenseItem: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var when: NSDate
    @NSManaged var location: String
    @NSManaged var what: String
    @NSManaged var howMuch: NSDecimalNumber

}
```

I call a function to create a NSManagedObject when unwinding the segue **either** from the prepareForSegue() of the DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol ExpenseItemManagementDelegate {
    func insertExpenseItem(something: String, somePrice: String, somewhere: String, sometime: NSDate)
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ExpenseItemManagementDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var whenInput: UIDatePicker!

    @IBOutlet weak var whatInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var locationInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceInput: UITextField!

    var expenseItem: ExpenseItem? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let item: AnyObject = self.expenseItem {
            if let input = self.whenInput {
                input.date = item.valueForKey("when")! as NSDate
            }
            if let input = self.whatInput {
                input.text = item.valueForKey("what")! as String
            }
            if let input = self.locationInput {
                input.text = item.valueForKey("location")! as String
            }
            if let input = self.priceInput {
                input.text = item.valueForKey("howMuch")! as String
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        delegate.insertExpenseItem(self.whatInput!.text,somePrice:self.priceInput!.text,somewhere:self.locationInput!.text,sometime:self.whenInput!.date)
    }
}
```

**Or** from the unwindToSegue() of the MasterViewController:

```
@IBAction func unwindToSegue (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let dvc: DetailViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? DetailViewController
    {
        self.insertExpenseItem(dvc.whatInput!.text,somePrice:dvc.priceInput!.text,somewhere:dvc.locationInput!.text,sometime:dvc.whenInput!.date)
    }
}
```

(Obviously, I use do not call the function from both places at the same time)

Unwinding the segue by clicking on Cancel or Save in the DetailViewController navigation bar call the insertExpenseItem() function, and the data from the inputs is not used to create the NSManagedObject.

```
func insertExpenseItem(something: String, somePrice: String, somewhere: String, sometime: NSDate) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let expenseManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ExpenseItem", inManagedObjectContext: context) as ExpenseItem
    expenseManagedObject.what = "big mac" // you can now use dot syntax instead of setValue
    expenseManagedObject.howMuch = 500
    expenseManagedObject.location = "macdo"
    expenseManagedObject.when = NSDate()

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
}
```

I try to set the values in the custom cell labels in the configureCell():

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as ExpenseItem
    let expenseItem = cell as ExpenseItemTableViewCell
    expenseItem.whenLabel.text = object.when.description
    expenseItem.whatLabel.text = object.what
    expenseItem.locationLabel.text = object.location
    expenseItem.priceLabel.text = object.howMuch.description
    expenseItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}
```

The problem I encounter is in controllerDidChangeContent():

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    // * or *
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

- if I call self.tableView.reloadData(), configureCell() does not get called and the table view displays an entirely blank space in the place the cell should be, but the app does not crash
- if I call self.tableView.endUpdates(), configureCell() does get called, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=...) error

**Update 2014/12/08**
Here is the stack trace :

```
Thread 1
Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000010a3c6324 in CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) ()
[...]
#50 0x000000010a3c639a in CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) ()
#130390 0x000000010a3c639a in CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) ()
[...]
#130540 0x000000010a3c639a in CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) ()
#130541 0x000000010a3cdd63 in CA::Layer::insert_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*, unsigned long) ()
#130542 0x000000010a3ce14a in -[CALayer addSublayer:] ()
#130543 0x00000001064d2e30 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] ()
#130544 0x00000001067d9e01 in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager layoutSubviewsOfCell:] ()
#130545 0x00000001066ec1d0 in -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] ()
#130546 0x00000001064d5973 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#130547 0x000000010a3d3de8 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#130548 0x000000010a3c8a0e in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#130549 0x00000001064c9847 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] ()
#130550 0x00000001064cd5ce in +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] ()
#130551 0x00000001065378de in __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke919 ()
#130552 0x00000001064ce362 in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] ()
#130553 0x00000001064ce5b7 in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] ()
#130554 0x0000000106536c71 in -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] ()
#130555 0x0000000106530ce7 in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] ()
#130556 0x0000000105621c3b in myExpenseBook.MasterViewController.controllerDidChangeContent (myExpenseBook.MasterViewController)(ObjectiveC.NSFetchedResultsController) -> () at /Users/Ailete619/Desktop/myExpenseBook/myExpenseBook/MasterViewController.swift:241
#130557 0x0000000105621e2a in @objc myExpenseBook.MasterViewController.controllerDidChangeContent (myExpenseBook.MasterViewController)(ObjectiveC.NSFetchedResultsController) -> () ()
#130558 0x0000000105816241 in __77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke ()
#130559 0x00000001058150b2 in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] ()
#130560 0x0000000105ba0cec in __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ ()
#130561 0x0000000105aa08a4 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#130562 0x0000000105fa96b8 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#130563 0x000000010572cc96 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] ()
#130564 0x00000001057b5d1e in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] ()
#130565 0x00000001057283d1 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] ()
#130566 0x000000010572b8f3 in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] ()
#130567 0x000000010561709d in myExpenseBook.MasterViewController.insertExpenseItem (myExpenseBook.MasterViewController)(Swift.String, somePrice : Swift.String, somewhere : Swift.String, sometime : ObjectiveC.NSDate) -> () at /Users/Ailete619/Desktop/myExpenseBook/myExpenseBook/MasterViewController.swift:48
#130568 0x00000001056193af in myExpenseBook.MasterViewController.unwindToSegue (myExpenseBook.MasterViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue) -> () at /Users/Ailete619/Desktop/myExpenseBook/myExpenseBook/MasterViewController.swift:95
#130569 0x000000010561948a in @objc myExpenseBook.MasterViewController.unwindToSegue (myExpenseBook.MasterViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue) -> () ()
#130570 0x0000000106b28c2f in -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] ()
#130571 0x000000010645d8be in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#130572 0x000000010645d8be in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#130573 0x0000000106564410 in -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#130574 0x00000001065637df in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#130575 0x00000001064a3308 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#130576 0x00000001064a3c33 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#130577 0x00000001064709b1 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#130578 0x000000010647da7d in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent ()
#130579 0x0000000106459103 in _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue ()
#130580 0x0000000105b06551 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#130581 0x0000000105afc41d in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#130582 0x0000000105afba54 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#130583 0x0000000105afb486 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#130584 0x0000000109cc79f0 in GSEventRunModal ()
#130585 0x000000010645c420 in UIApplicationMain ()
#130586 0x000000010561280e in top_level_code at /Users/Ailete619/Desktop/myExpenseBook/myExpenseBook/AppDelegate.swift:13
#130587 0x000000010561284a in main ()
#130588 0x0000000107eee145 in start ()
#130589 0x0000000107eee145 in start ()
```

I checked my managed object was created by modifying controllerDidChangeContent():

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let objects = context.registeredObjects
    println("l=\(objects.count)")
    for o in objects {
        let e = o as ExpenseItem
        println("o when=\(e.when) what=\(e.what) location=\(e.location) price=\(e.howMuch)")
    }
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

and got this output:

```
l=1
o when=2014-12-08 13:20:49 +0000 what=big mac location=macdo price=500
```

My test project is downloadable at: ailete619com.appspot.com/stackoverflow/myExpenseBook.zip

Comment: Still looking for ideas of what I am doing wrong and how to find the cause of my crash ...

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging this by putting setting an exception breakpoint in Xcode. Then you'll know exactly what is crashing. It's likely that it's not the table view itself, but something involving your Core Data stack or other data source.

Comment: I set an exception breakpoint but I do not get any message except all my println messages ... I do not get an exception message

Answer (score 0):

Just call `insertExpenseItem` from DestinationViewController in `prepareForSegue` message. You can change it to expect ExpenseItem instead of all parameters.

Comment: You mean that creating the ExpenseItem in the DetailViewController would solve the crash problem? Because I tried calling insertExpenseItem() from DestinationViewController in prepareForSegue() as you can see in the code I added above.